# Elasticsearch snapshot by node

Tags: elasticsearch

elasticsearch snapshot defaults to index units.
However, I would like to use snapshot on a per-node basis.
For example, if `myIndex` exists on three nodes, I want to save only `myIndex` of node 1 as a snapshot and restore it.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible and doesn't even make sense. Your index is allocated into 5 primary shards by default and shards are distributed across the 3 nodes. What is the use of taking a snapshot of just 1 or 2 shards out of the 5 which cannot be used for restore purposes ?

Answer (score 0):

Elasticsearch snapshots work on indices basis . Hence you can't snapshot single node of elasticsearch.

In your scenario , I would suggest to breakdown  `myIndex` into exact number of indices as number of nodes in your cluster. For example if your cluster have 3 nodes, I will distribute the data among `myIndex1` , `myIndex2`, `myIndex3` and route them to each nodes (individual mapping can be tricky but doable). This way you can can take snapshot of single index which eventually will be your existing indices's data on single node.